# want to make a field read only when i selected a picklist value

Tags: page-layout, configuration

I am having an Opportunity object there is a field named "stage(picklist)", when I selected "selected won" from picklist "amount" field must become "read only"

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative, you could also create a validation rule that doen't allow changes to the amount field when the stage is in Closed Won.

So for example:

AND( ISPICKVAL(StageName, "Closed Won") , ISCHANGED(Amount) )

The dis-advantage with this solution however is that your user will only get this error message on-save while with a record type / page layout change, they would immediatly see that they can't change the amount field anymore.

An advantage is though that you don't need a seperate recordtype / page layout to maintain.

Probably depends if there would also be other fields that users would not be allowed to change anymore, then a recordtype / page layout would be better.
If it's only one field that they can't change anymore, validation rule would be easier to maintain.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by assigning a different record type with a workflow. This record type would have a separate pagelayout with the fields you require to be read only set as such.

Comment: +1 Sdry : Create a page layout i.e clone the exsiting page and make amount read only on the cloned page layout. Now write a workflow field update with condition if stage=selected won.it has to populate cloned page.
here is the link for detail explaination.https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000gilKAAQ

Answer (score 0):

You may have to explore VisualForce pages. You can embed one in the Opportunity layout and have it act upon your fields.

Having said that, I would recommend allowing the user change the amount until the record is actually saved, in which case a few of the solutions mentioned above would do.

Answer (score 0):

You give a try with validation rule for your case with reference to this example - http://www.techlogbooks.com/2019/02/how-to-prevent-changes-to-field-in.html

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. Please read [answer] and [edit] this post so that the complete solution is described here. Links can go dead and we ask that users not need to navigate away to understand the solution.